# Привязать файл с формой к html странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, уже несколько дней мучаюсь.
У меня есть файл form.html данная обратная форма модальная и работает когда я нажимаю на кнопку которая создана в файле  form.html. А мне нужно кнопку "Заказать" перенести на index.html, чтоб при нажатии она так же срабатывала как внутри. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Я уже и js отдельно выносил, но почему то не хочет она работать.